# Procedural Text in Video Sequence Editor

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

I was wondering if there is a way to create procedural text in the text Effect Strip. Something so I can clearly see the name of images shown, the frame of the video, and the time in an video sequence. Something similar to some tricks in AE or Shotcut filters that have copy and paste features for their filters.

Shotcut:

[image]

I tried doing this manually, and I'm trying to add it to hundres of images which is too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add stamp like this in **Render** -> **Metadata** section:

[image]

There is now so much settings, but you can bake over image a strip name, labels of markers, frame number and time here.

Comment: Awesome! thanks you! this is what i was looking for! Is there any way to change the locations that the metadata appear?

Comment: As I said,there isn't so much settings..